# how do I make multiple integers pass multiple functions?

Tags: c++

In this code I am trying to output the sum and difference of two inputs.
When I run this program, the sum outputs fine, but instead of the difference, the first input outputs.
How can I make this program output the difference as well as the sum?

```cpp
void Modify(int *x, int *y) {
    *x = *x + *y;
    
    if (*x >= *y)
        *y = *x - *y;
    if (*x < *y)
        *y = *y - *x;
                
}

int main() {
    
    int x, y;
    
    int *ptr_x = &x;
    int *ptr_y = &y;
    
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
    
    Modify(ptr_x, ptr_y);
    
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << y;
                 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After changing the value at `x` some crafty thinking will be required to use the previous value in future operations. You may want to employ a temporary variable.

Comment: if I cant change anything bellow int main, is there a way I can make a temporary variable?

Comment: Put the temporary variable above `int main` where it is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void Modify(int *x, int *y) {
    *x = *x + *y;
    
    if (*x >= *y)
        *y = *x - *y;
    if (*x < *y)
        *y = *y - *x;
                
}
```

Your first line `*x = *x + *y;` overwrites `*x` value with `*x + *y`, by consequence the next statements are misleading

```
    if (*x >= *y)
        *y = *x - *y;
    if (*x < *y)
        *y = *y - *x;
```

and are not performing what you expect.

As a general advice, keep your code simple and clear about your intends:

```
#include <cmath>

void Modify(int *x, int *y) {

    using std::abs;

    int sum      = *x + *y;
    int abs_diff = abs(*x - *y);
    
    *x = sum;
    *y = abs_diff;
}
```

Comment: The clarity alone is worth the nod.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you explain why you cannot do something simple as `std::cout << x + y << endl << x - y;` without calling any function.

But if you want to do it that way, without extra variables, one option is this:

```
void Modify(int *x, int *y) {
    *x = *x + *y;      ///x = original x + original y
    *y = *x - 2*(*y);  ///y = (original x + original y) - 2*(original y)        
}
```

Note: Be carefull with overflows

Edit: If you want absolute value of the difference, use instead `*y = abs(*x - 2*(*y))`;

Answer (score 1):

This is not printing difference because you update the value of `x` with the sum of both at `*x = *x + *y` as @user4581301 suggested in the comment. You can do something like this.

```
 
void Modify(int *x, int *y) {
    int* temp = new int(*x);
    *x = *temp + *y;
    
    if (*temp >= *y)
        *y = *temp - *y;
    if (*x < *y)
        *y = *y - *temp;
    delete temp;
}
```

What this will do is you will create an new integer pointer`temp` will store the value of `x` and now you can change `x` but on other places where `x` was needed we will use `temp` instead of x. And at the end we are deleting the `temp`.

Comment: Any reason `int temp = *x;` wouldn't work? Allocating for one `int` may become expensive if the function is called repeatedly. Any reason why you are not using `if (*temp < *y)`?